# Facebook default address concatenation for fanpage

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access event data on public fanpages (pages which are places, so they have their adresses)

The problem is that some pages organize events which are not held in the same venue the page has. I mean: `page venue != event venue`.

That wouldn't be a problem, because most events have a venue attribute attached. So i can parse that, great! It usually contains id of a page, I can grab lat and lng and I'm home.

**But for some events the `venue` `id` isn't there. Only `name` value which contains address.**

Now, I would like to make comparison between *page->location* and the address returned by the *page->event->venue->name*. **The problem is that location is a JSON object containing few characteristics of location and the second one is a pre-concatenated string.**

```
   "name": "someClub",
   "location": {
      "street": "happy street",
      "city": "City",
      "country": "Country",
      "zip": "02-591",
      "latitude": 22.00,
      "longitude": 21.00


   "name": "happy street, 02-591 City, Country",
```

I have a suspicion that the way it's concatenated is locale specific. So simply concatenating it this way won't suffice (as the project is international). **Question: Would someone tell me if there's way to obtain a pre-concatenated address for the page or if this way of concat is default for fb?**

Comment: Similar issue here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11858973/fql-query-for-event-table-returns-venue-name-instead-of-venue-id/11860360

Comment: Yep, the initial problem is the same, but I accept the issue that it sometimes return name and sometimes id (it's because of the way that fanpage owners make their events - they either input a fanpage as a place or an address). I ask about the concatenation specifically

Comment: Btw, for now I ended up concatenating it the way described in the post and then comparing it with php's `similar_text()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, sorry. Are you trying to see if venue_address == page_address when one is a JSON containing the data and the other is a string?

Comment: Yes. Both are JSON returned by FQL. One is a pre-concatenated string. The other is a set of JSON strings. Question: is the first one concatenated in some standardized, locale-independent way.